# Do all cars rust eventually even with repeated proper rustproofing methods?

Tags: maintenance, rust, theory

My understanding is that rustproofing works and lasts when done properly, but once the coating used to rustproof wears off I'm guessing the process to rustproof needs to be done all over again. With this logic, my question is, can you repeatedly rustproof a car and essentially never have it ever rust?

Comment: Define what you mean by "eventually" and "never" - what life are you after? 10 yrs, 20 yrs, 50, 100??

Comment: There will always be some rust on a car, even if you treat the bottom side every now and then with rustproofing, because you CAN'T rust proof everything! Maybe if you do a full body off rustproofing but i doubt anyone will ever do that. But if you are only talking about the underside, if you maintain the rustproofing it can be so that the car does not rust at all. But only if it is maintained and done properly.

Comment: Along with what's mentioned in the comments already, it also depends on where the vehicle resides. If it's in an arid region, you'll most likely ***never*** need to worry about rust or rust proofing because there's never enough moisture to cause the condition.

Comment: "Rust never sleeps" , motto in the corrosion protection business.